# Accessing downloaded data in a Cloud Run instance

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I have a Google Cloud Run instance that looks like this:

```
import json
import os
import rarfile

from google.cloud import storage
from flask import Flask, request


app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/", methods=["POST"])
def index():
    file_id = request.values.get("fileId")
    try:
        storage_client = storage.Client()
        bucket = storage_client.get_bucket("test-bucket")
        blob = bucket.blob(file_id)
        blob.download_to_filename(file_id)
        rf = rarfile.RarFile(file_id)
        rf.extractall()
        return ("", 204)
    except Exception as e:
        return f"Error: {e}", 400

    return ("500 Error", 500)
```

However, when I trigger the instance, I get the following error:

```
Error: can only concatenate str (not "RarCannotExec") to str
```

What is going wrong here? When I download the file and unzip in locally, I run into no problems. Does it have to do with the file system of Cloud Run instances?

EDIT:
I think from above it is clear that the error is from the `except` where I return `Error: {e}`. However, from analyzing the logs, it is apparent that the program fails at the `rf = rarfile.RarFile(file_id)` line. That, I am still unclear on.

EDIT 2:
I need to install either `unrar` or `unrar-free` to the container. Cheers!

Comment: What is the filename you're downloading the blob to?

Comment: do you have the trace of the error? the full log can help to sewhat is going on.

Comment: @DustinIngram I tried file_id + ".rar" and that did not change the result.

Comment: I mean: where on the filesystem are you trying to write it? In the current working directory?

Comment: This is most likely a program bug, and most likely doesn't work on your machine either. Try local debugging first: https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/testing/local